# Permissions [Errno 13] error running Python in Docker with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, docker, lambda

I have a simple python script in lambda_handler.py:

```
def handler(event, context):
    print("success")
    return "Success"
```

and I am packaging it in Docker to run on AWS Lambda.

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY lambda_handler.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN yum install -y gcc-c++ pkgconfig poppler-cpp-devel
RUN pip install selenium boto3 --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

CMD ["lambda_handler.handler"]
```

However, when the lambda is invoked I am getting an permissions error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/lambda_handler.py'",
  "errorType": "PermissionError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 846, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 982, in get_code\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 1039, in get_data\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [AWS Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-deployment.html) the lambda runtime needs to have permissions to read the files in the deployment package.

Running:
`chmod 644 lambda_handler.py` on my local machine before running `docker build` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The file was already 644 on the local file system but I had to add a `RUN chmod 644 lambda_handler.py` to the docker file to remove this error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34946978)